# Is dependent probability the same as conditional probability?

Tags: probability

I can't find any solid definition online. A few websites however say "dependent probability is defined when a previous event will affect the next event. This gives rise to conditional probability" which is really vague. What's the difference? Are they the same?

I am also confused with a few definitions. If independent probability is defined as $P(A) = P(A\mid B) = P(A\mid B')$, how can you show that in a Venn/Euler diagram? It seems in that case, the probability theorems cannot be translated into a diagram!

Answer (score 1):

Independence and dependence have nothing to do with Venn diagram. Since $A,B$ are independent does not mean $A$ and $B$ are separated.

Here is an example, Let $\Omega = \{a,b,c\}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be a sigma algebra with $\mathcal{A} = \{\varnothing,\Omega, \{a\},\{b,c\}\}$. Clearly, $\mathcal{A}$ is the sigma algebra generated by $\{a\}$. We let the probability of events in $\mathcal{A}$ be equally distributed. Then for the events $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$, $P(A=\{a\}) =  0.25$, $P(B = \Omega)=0.25$. Clearly, the event $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{\Omega\}$ is independent, but $A\cap B = \{a\}\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: Oh ok. I was under the impression that any probability expression written using the probability notation could be translated graphically. Is this not the case? It does work with many other expressions (especially conditional probabilities + venn diagram).

Comment: I note you say dependence has nothing to do with Venn diagrams. Are you implying that dependence and conditional probability are separate?